# Using Java Reflection, can you detect if a method is Native or not?

Tags: java, reflection, native

Using Java Reflection, you can detect all methods and their returns type. But is there a way to detect if a method is declared as `native` or not?

Comment: You can detect all the modifiers of a method (even generated ones) Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Using powermock, I need to suppress all Native methods in a certain class

Comment: you can: `Method.getModifier()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.The method `getModifiers()` returns an int which applied the right mask can tell you if the method is native or not

I would suggest doing it like this, for convenience:

```
   int modifiers = myMethod.getModifiers(); 
   boolean isNative = Modifier.isNative(modifiers);
```

The Modifier class is an utility specialized class meant to apply the appropriate masks in order to discover the modifiers of the method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have accepted the fastest one as all answered my question correctly :)

Comment: @AdelBoutros: I don't think so, I don't know how to check. Anyway, it doesn't matter !

Comment: At the top of the answers, you have 3 tabs **active**, **oldest**, **votes**. If you click on oldest, you get the answers in the order they have appeared from the oldest (at the top) to the most recent (at the bottom)

Comment: Yes, what I was looking for was an edit history of each answer.

Comment: His answer was not edited, It was deleted and replaced with a newer. The newer one which is currently displayed was still older than yours

Answer (score 5):

You can check the modifiers associated with the method. The example below prints all the native methods of Object:

```
for (Method m : methods) {
    int mod = m.getModifiers();
    if ((mod & Modifier.NATIVE) != 0) {
        System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
}
```

EDIT

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869682/829571) gives a better approach that avoids the bitwise matching part.

Comment: What if the method is not native but is called notnative()? This would incorrectly be included as a native method.

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering why you do the flag check yourself, instead of using a method that already does that for you.

Comment: @DennisMeng The alternative approach is indeed better. But another answer had already used it when I wrote mine so I thought I would leave my post as is. I have edited to link to it.

Answer (score 5):

Method has a `getModifiers()` method which returns the modifiers as an int, and one of the modifiers is `Modifier.NATIVE`, which is what your looking for. `Modifier.isNative()` can be used to decode the argument from `getModifiers()`.

(Basically, if you have your method as a Method object named `m`, then `Modifier.isNative(m.getModifiers())` should do it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have accepted the fastest one as all answered my question correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, just check the modifiers of the method:

```
public class NativeMethodModifierTest
{
    public class NativeMethodTest
    {
        public native void method();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNativeMember()
    {
        Method m = NativeMethodTest.class.getMethods()[0];
        Assert.assertEquals(Modifier.NATIVE, (m.getModifiers() & Modifier.NATIVE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have accepted the fastest one as all answered my question correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`getModifiers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers%28%29), you can read the flags using the utility functions in [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html):

```
Methods meth = Object.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
int mod = meth.getModifiers();
boolean native = Modifier.isNative(mod);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have accepted the fastest one as all answered my question correctly :)